# How can I access some object from `Any` Type?

Tags: ios, swift, dictionary, swift3, xcode8

In Swift 2.2, I used to write like this

```
let dict = [String: AnyObject]()
let value = dict.objectForKey("price") as! Double
print(value)
```

But as `AnyObject` is now replaced with type `Any` how can I access dictionary values as no method for `objectForKey` for type Any.
Do i need to type cast to `AnyObject`?

Comment: swift 2.2 also gives error for Value of type '[String : AnyObject]' has no member 'objectForKey'

Comment: you can directly access the value let value = dict["price"] as! Double

Comment: just subscript the dictionary.  let dict: [String: Any] = ["price": 2.0 ]
 if let value = dict["price"] as? Double {
  print(value)
}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you can't use `objectForKey` for swift native type. you can simply use subscript as i mentioned in comments  and also use if let for safely unwrap.

```
 let dict: [String: Any] = ["price": 2.0 ]
 if let value = dict["price"] as? Double {
  print(value)
}
```

**Note:**
As always, do not use  NSMutableDictionary in Swift. this type lack type information

Answer (score 2):

Try like this.

```
let dict: [String: Any] = ["value1":1.5,"value2":2.5]
if let value = dict["value1"] as? Double {
    print(value)
}
```

Check [IBM Swift Sandbox](http://swiftlang.ng.bluemix.net/#/repl/58007617483d56547ef0cf33) for demo to run.

**Note:** In Swift it is batter if you use `subscript` instead of `value(for:)` and `object(for:)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this...

```
let dict :  [String: Any] = [:]
let value = dict["price"] as! Double
print(value)
```

Comment: I don't want to use AnyObject any more i need to use Any. Yes with AnyObject i can use the old methods

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be using [`objectForKey(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdictionary/1414347-objectforkey) is a method on [`NSDictionary`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nsdictionary/). Up until Swift 2.3, you could call this `NSDictionary` method on a Swift [`Dictionary`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/dictionary) because there was implicit bridging from Swift's `Dictionary` to `NSDictionary`. In an effort to move away from `Foundation` data types, this implicit bridging was removed in Swift 3. There was no reason to be using it in the first place, if you're working with Swift's `Dictionary`.

Just [subscript](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/dictionary/1540848-subscript) the [`Dictionary`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/dictionary):

```
let dict: [String: Any] = ["name": "apple", "price": 1.0]
let value = dict["price"] as! Double
```